# Insert results of bash script into html table

Tags: html, linux, bash, logging, server

I have a script that outputs the last 3 logs of an application. I'm looking for this data to be placed into a HTML table that i'm able to send out to my colleagues.

Below is the command that I have at the moment but it isn't printing out what I'm looking for.

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{print "<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=0 bordercolor=BLACK>
<tr>
    <td>Environment</td>
    <td>Default Shell</td>
</tr>"}{ print "
<tr>
    <td>"$success"</td>
    <td>"$(NF)"</td>
</tr>"$(NF)"</td></tr>"}END { print "</table>" } ' /var/tmp/pid_test.sh
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Now if we knew  what `/var/tmp/pid_test.sh` looks like (btw, .sh is an odd extension for a logfile?), and what your desired output is ...

Comment: what is it printing, and why didn't you tag your post with `awk`?  Based on file name, I would guess you need the output of the script not the text of the script.

Comment: I'm pulling in the logs in my `/var/tmp/pid_test.sh` file.
Yeah i would need the output of the script, and not the text.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{your script that prints output} | awk ...
```

e.g.

```
$ echo -e "a:1\nb:2" | 
awk -F: 'BEGIN {print "<table>"}
               {print "<tr><td>" $NF "</td></tr>"}
         END   {print "</table>"}'
```

gives

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

pipe to

```
$ script ... | awk ... | mailx -s "test results" test@example.com
```